# Assume multiply roles the same time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I have an EKS instance located in an account A. From an account B I have two roles, former for S3 access in the account B and latter for dynamodb access in the account B. These roles have trusted relationships with the account A.

Is it possible to have simultaneous access to these resources in account B from the EKS located in the account A?

Also, I must have access to resources in the account A: S3 and dynamodb.

So, a single pod in the EKS (in the account A) must have these accesses:

- Access to S3 in the account B with a dedicated trusted role in the account B
- Access to DynamoDB in the account B with a dedicated trusted role in account B
- Access to some resources in the account A

Can I organize that without rearranging roles in the account B?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a way to assume multiple roles at the same the but it'll not be the union of permissions of both because when you assume role you get the temporary credentials. And requests made with these temporary credentials are authorized against the permissions granted to that role.

Every request is performed by a single principal, so if you are trying to perform a single action that requires the union of the permissions of multiple roles, that's a not possible.